# Best practice to make sure Objective-C Dictionary key is consistent throughout the application?

Tags: objective-c, dictionary

If I defined a Dictionary with some values that I want to pass to another class. Should I make the keys as constant so I could use them in the other class without worrying about if I typed it correctly. What is the common standered in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If making all the allowed dictionary keys constants is a possibility, you might as well make a custom class with the corresponding fields, and pass that class instead of a dictionary. Users of your class would be able to use key-value programming to retrieve field values, too, if they need to access fields through symbols that are not available at compile time.

If you must pass a dictionary for some other reason, you could make an `enum` with keys, and prefix `enum` values with `@` to wrap them into `NSNumber` objects automatically:

```
enum {
    kFirstKey
,   kSecondKey
,   kThirdKey
};
...
NSDictionary *dict = @{
    @(kFirstKey) : @"Quick"
,   @(kSecondKey) : @"brown"
    @(kThirdKey) : @"fox"
};
```

Comment: I think it's more common just to make constant NSStrings. That way you aren't constantly having to do the `@()` ritual.

Comment: I could use a custom class, so for example do you think is common in ObjC to create a custom class for http request e.g.: RegistrationRequest and pass it to registration class that will use the request to post the values ?

Comment: @Jimmy Using objects of a custom class for dictionary keys seems like an overkill, although there is certainly nothing wrong with it. My exposure to iOS code written by others is minimal, bud judging from the Cocoa framework design, it is not very common: Apple uses `enum`s all over the place. However, I would definitely agree that Apple may be constrained by the need to maintain legacy code.

Answer (score -1):

You can use an `enum` and use `NSNumber` to box the keys.

Some header file:

```
typedef enum {
    DictionaryKeyOneKey,
    DictionaryKeyAnotherKey
} DictionaryKey;
```

You can define a convenience method or macro for boxing the key:

```
#define boxKey(k) [NSNumber numberWithInt:k]
```

Then in client code:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict;
...
NSObject *object = [dict objectForValue:boxKey(DictionaryKeyOneKey)];
[dict setObject:object forKey:boxKey(DictionaryKeyAnotherKey)];
```